# syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am attempting to get this going:
http://github.com/xaviershay/db2s3

I created a file in config/initializers/db2s3.rb

```
     DB2S3::Config.instance_eval do
       S3 = {
       :access_key_id     => 'id',
       :secret_access_key => 'key',
       :bucket            => 'name'
    }
  end
```

In the rake file I added:

```
require 'db2s3/tasks'
```

But when I attempt to run the rake task to push it into s3 I get an error.

> rake db2s3:backup:full
>
> ...../config/initializers/db2s3.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end

Comment: For a start, there aren't 13 lines in that file you posted so figuring out which is line 13 is pretty damned hard for us :-) My suggestion is that you post the whole thing (sanitised of personal information of course).

Comment: Actually that is the entire file.  I had some other lines after what you see here in it earlier which I realized were not supposed to be in there.  I'm not sure why it said 13 lines even after I removed the lines.  Maybe the whitespace was causing this somehow?  I ran the backspace over the end of the file and it works now.  Not sure if that is causal or coincidental.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a text encoding problem.

You might want to try creating a new file and typing out the entire contents instead of copying and pasting from the source.  Be sure to save the new file and/or overwrite the old file so that the old contents are not used.